# links load on same page with # in URL

Tags: jquery

I started using this jQuery [template](https://github.com/commadelimited/jQuery-Mobile-Bootstrap-Theme).

When I click on links I have setup on my navbar, the page loads but the URL is something like this `index.php#page2.php`. What is this called/where is it coming from?

How can I avoid it from happening for certain links? I need certain links to reload the entire page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a hash, it loads in the url when dynamic content is updated and it updates the url with the intent of NOT reloading the entire page.  You'll have to update the links in the navbar and change the href for what your needs are.

The reason the hash is used, as it's not actually necessary for the dynamic updating.  It's to give the webpage a different url for the different content that the page holds.  The reason the hash is used is because (with the exception of HTML5), you can't change the url text without refreshing the page...unless it's a hash, which tells the browser that the target is part of the current page.

Comment: How does I change the hrefs such that hashs don't happen?